# Why does splitChunks: 'initial' not generate a separate chunk in my project?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

Here are the files in my project, and the `webpack.config.js`.

```js
//index.js
import './a';
import './b';
```

```js
//a.js
import './helpers'
```

```js
//b.js
import './helpers'
```

```js
//webpack.config.js
const path = require("path");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'initial'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Both `a.js` and `b.js` import `helpers.js`. And `helpers.js` are larger than 30kb in size. I think `helpers.js` will be split into a separate chunk. But in fact the result I get is this:
[image]

What I'm wondering about are:

1. Why did `a.js` and `b.js` not appear in the final result?
2. Why was `helpers.js` not split into a separate chunk?

Answer (score 1):

There is [a minimum size for a chunk](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksminsize) to be generated. It's about **20 KB**.

To remove the limitaion, you need to specify the `splitChunks.minSize` to zero.

The splitChunks should look like this:

```
splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
    minSize: 0,
    cacheGroups: {
        default: {
            // get all modules excluding entry points
            // entry point will be separate anyway
            test: module => !module.isEntryModule(),
            name: module => {
                const matchName = module.identifier().match(/(\w+)\.js$/)

                // name chunk like 'a', 'b' or 'helpers'.
                // by default it's 'a_js' for some reason
                return matchName[1]
            }
        }
    }
}
```